# Collapse rows that match in more than one column

Tags: r, aggregate, r-collapse

I have a data frame where in the first column I have a `Patient ID` and in the second column I have a `Date` (date time) when a specific test was taken. The columns thereafter are columns of the specific tests (`b`, `a`, `c`, `d`). At the moment, for every `Patient ID` and every `Date` I have a row with the results of the specific test and `NA` in the columns of all other tests.

[image]

I want to collapse the data frame in a way that whenever `Patient ID` and `Date` match, the test results are collapsed into one row only.

I have tried `aggregate()`, `collapse()`, and `group_by()`, but did not manage to do this. The functions are only activated when `Patient ID` and `Date` match, not just one of the columns.

Comment: please post your data as text (eg. via `dput`) in order to make your [example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example). Also, you're looking for something like [`reshape`, `(d)cast` or `pivot_(wider/longer)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5890584/how-to-reshape-data-from-long-to-wide-format)

Answer (score 1):

Data copied from picture:

```r
X = read.table(text = "PatientID Date b a c d
               1 2024-03-0420:16:11 0.4 NA NA NA 
               1 2024-03-0422:40:11 NA TRUE NA NA 
               1 2024-03-0522:40:11 NA NA FALSE NA
               1 2024-03-0622:40:11 NA NA NA Strong
               2 2024-03-0422:40:11 NA NA NA Weak
               2 2024-03-0522:40:11 NA NA FALSE NA
               3 2024-03-0622:40:11 0.6 NA NA NA
               3 2024-03-0622:40:11 NA FALSE NA NA", header = TRUE)
```

Extract `Date` (please specify `tz` (time zone)). You probably need to adapt `format`. This step is needed due the bad data structure (I needed to copy the data from picture). Then `aggregate`:

```r
X$Date = as.Date(as.POSIXct(X$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d%H:%M:%S"), tz = "")
aggregate(. ~ PatientID + Date, data = X, FUN = na.omit, na.action = "na.pass")
```

gives

```r
  PatientID       Date   b     a     c      d
1         1 2024-03-04 0.4  TRUE             
2         2 2024-03-04                   Weak
3         1 2024-03-05           FALSE       
4         2 2024-03-05           FALSE       
5         1 2024-03-06                 Strong
6         3 2024-03-06 0.6 FALSE
```

If you don't like the order, change it. E.g. `PatientID` in ascending order as the raw data (`X`) is organised:

```r
> Y = aggregate(. ~ PatientID + Date, data = X, FUN = na.omit, na.action = "na.pass")
> Y[order(Y$PatientID), ]
  PatientID       Date   b     a     c      d
1         1 2024-03-04 0.4  TRUE             
3         1 2024-03-05           FALSE       
5         1 2024-03-06                 Strong
2         2 2024-03-04                   Weak
4         2 2024-03-05           FALSE       
6         3 2024-03-06 0.6 FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you need; here's a `tidyverse` solution:

```
X %>%
  group_by(PatientID, Date) %>%
  summarise(
            a = str_c(a[!is.na(a)], collapse = ","),
            b = str_c(b[!is.na(b)], collapse = ","),
            c = str_c(c[!is.na(c)], collapse = ","),
            d = str_c(d[!is.na(d)], collapse = ",")) %>%
  mutate(across(a:d, ~na_if(., "")))
# A tibble: 7 × 6
# Groups:   PatientID [3]
  PatientID Date               a     b     c     d     
      <int> <chr>              <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> 
1         1 2024-03-0420:16:11 NA    0.4   NA    NA    
2         1 2024-03-0422:40:11 TRUE  NA    NA    NA    
3         1 2024-03-0522:40:11 NA    NA    FALSE NA    
4         1 2024-03-0622:40:11 NA    NA    NA    Strong
5         2 2024-03-0422:40:11 NA    NA    NA    Weak  
6         2 2024-03-0522:40:11 NA    NA    FALSE NA    
7         3 2024-03-0622:40:11 FALSE 0.6   NA    NA
```

Data (thks to @Friede):

```
X = read.table(text = "PatientID Date b a c d
               1 2024-03-0420:16:11 0.4 NA NA NA 
               1 2024-03-0422:40:11 NA TRUE NA NA 
               1 2024-03-0522:40:11 NA NA FALSE NA
               1 2024-03-0622:40:11 NA NA NA Strong
               2 2024-03-0422:40:11 NA NA NA Weak
               2 2024-03-0522:40:11 NA NA FALSE NA
               3 2024-03-0622:40:11 0.6 NA NA NA
               3 2024-03-0622:40:11 NA FALSE NA NA", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Are you ignoring `PatientID` on purpose?

Comment: No, have overlooked it. But see revised solution.